# Google has changed appearance using Safari 5.1.1

Tags: safari, google

The way google is presenting as of today is totally different and I can no longer get the image pages so you can scroll the images before selecting one you want to see. Now there are individual boxes that click through. The entire appearance makes it no longer usuable.. Is there I can do to revert back to the way it was previously?  It shows perfectly on Firefox and nothing has changed there.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Safari 5.1.1, web and images searches have a left-hand column with sorting features, and the image search gives small thumbnails which take you directly to original site. Hate it. Trying to go back to old view. I've cleared cookies, but no luck...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's an example of a new policy from Google, where they're deliberately showing old versions of their search pages if you use an out of date browser. You can find information about this from, for example, this [BBC news report](http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-29012038).

It's probably a good idea to update Safari, for security reasons. This is what Google are trying to get you to do. But if you have a good reason to keep using 5.1.1, you can see an up-to-date Google homepage by changing the user agent string. There are instructions for doing this available online, e.g. [here](http://osxdaily.com/2013/01/16/change-user-agent-chrome-safari-firefox/).

Answer (score 0):

First I recommend you should update your Safari app.

I just made a comparison using the same web site for Images.

My Safari (7.0.6) + Chrome + Firefox show exactly the same.

The top row shows the categories you can select (also as images).

You can scroll down true the images or select a category.